# Converting Oracle to MySQL : Different Outputs Seen

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have an SQL query from Oracle which I am trying to convert to MySQL.

Below is part of the query from both. The database structure is different hence you will find the names of tables and columns to be different.

I do not get any results in MYSQL part when I run it, need help in finding out why?

**Oracle SQL Query :**

```
    (SELECT  all_ips.child_itm_num,
             pres.child_itm_num AS present,
             prev.child_itm_num AS potential_prev_version
     FROM
            (SELECT DISTINCT child_itm_num
             FROM    EDW.dpdm_bom bom
             WHERE   root_itm_num IN ('a','b')) all_ips,
            (SELECT DISTINCT child_itm_num
             FROM    EDW.dpdm_bom bom
             WHERE   root_itm_num = 'b') pres,
   (SELECT DISTINCT child_itm_num
    FROM    EDW.dpdm_bom bom
    WHERE   root_itm_num = 'a') prev 
     WHERE  SUBSTR(all_ips.child_itm_num,0,LENGTH(all_ips.child_itm_num) - 3) = SUBSTR(pres.child_itm_num, 0,LENGTH(pres.child_itm_num) - 3)
     AND    SUBSTR(prev.child_itm_num,0,LENGTH(prev.child_itm_num) - 3)       = SUBSTR(pres.child_itm_num, 0,LENGTH(pres.child_itm_num) - 3)
     AND    prev.child_itm_num NOT IN (SELECT child_itm_num 
                                       FROM    EDW.dpdm_bom bom
                                       WHERE   root_itm_num ='b'))
```

[image]

**MySQL Query :**

```
    (SELECT  all_ips.child_name,
             pres.child_name AS present,
             prev.child_name AS potential_prev_version
     FROM
            (SELECT DISTINCT child_name
             FROM    DPDM_BOM bom
             WHERE   child_name IN ('a','b')) all_ips,
            (SELECT DISTINCT child_name
             FROM    DPDM_BOM bom
             WHERE   revision_name = 'b') pres,
            (SELECT DISTINCT child_name
             FROM    DPDM_BOM bom
             WHERE   revision_name = 'a') prev 
  WHERE  SUBSTR(all_ips.child_name,0,LENGTH(all_ips.child_name) - 3) = SUBSTR(pres.child_name, 0,LENGTH(pres.child_name) - 3)
  AND    SUBSTR(prev.child_name,0,LENGTH(prev.child_name) - 3)       = SUBSTR(pres.child_name, 0,LENGTH(pres.child_name) - 3)
  AND    prev.child_name NOT IN (SELECT child_name 
                                       FROM    DPDM_BOM bom
                                       WHERE   revision_name = 'b'))
```

[image]

Please Help !

Anusha H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should replace `WHERE   child_name IN ('a','b')` with `WHERE   revision_name IN ('a','b')`. Also, use `CHAR_LENGTH` instead of `LENGTH` (although Mysql supports `LENTGH` too).

```
(SELECT  all_ips.child_name,
             pres.child_name AS present,
             prev.child_name AS potential_prev_version
     FROM
            (SELECT DISTINCT child_name
             FROM    DPDM_BOM bom
             WHERE   revision_name IN ('a','b')) all_ips,
            (SELECT DISTINCT child_name
             FROM    DPDM_BOM bom
             WHERE   revision_name = 'b') pres,
            (SELECT DISTINCT child_name
             FROM    DPDM_BOM bom
             WHERE   revision_name = 'a') prev 
  WHERE  SUBSTR(all_ips.child_name,0,CHAR_LENGTH(all_ips.child_name) - 3) = SUBSTR(pres.child_name, 0,CHAR_LENGTH(pres.child_name) - 3)
  AND    SUBSTR(prev.child_name,0,LENGTH(prev.child_name) - 3)       = SUBSTR(pres.child_name, 0,LENGTH(pres.child_name) - 3)
  AND    prev.child_name NOT IN (SELECT child_name 
                                       FROM    DPDM_BOM bom
                                       WHERE   revision_name = 'b'))
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: In my case I need to search for Child_name itself. Thanks.

Comment: But in your oracle query, you are searching for `root_itm_num IN ('a','b')`. It's equivalent in mysql schema is `revision_name IN ('a','b')`. Hence, I suggested.

Comment: Ah yes you are right ! I had to change it in a couple of other places too. Thanks :)